# array_flip and key search vs array_search benchmark

Tags: php, arrays, benchmarking

Consider the following block:

```php
if ($key = array_search($itemId, $allowedItems) !== false) {
    unset($allowedItems[$key]);
}
```

Would you think the usage of index search on the `allowedItems` performance boost justify the following refactoring:

```php
$flipped = array_flip($allowedItems);
if (isset($flipped[$itemId])) {
    unset($allowedItems[$flipped[$itemId]]);
}
```

The array is consisted by item id integers:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 423
    [1] => 12
    [2] => 9990
)
```

Would the usage of an additional array variable (`$flipped`) overcome any gains?

The above block is an extract from a legacy module and it is executed *in a loop*.

Comment: Would use a bit of extra space, but would boost performance in terms of time complexity. But, note that, duplicate values would be overwritten.

Comment: You should time them and see, however in the first you are searching twice, just do it once `if ($ruleMatch && $exclude && ($key = array_search($itemId, $allowedItems))!==false) {`

Comment: @AbraCadaver Yes, this should definitely change, thanks. I'm updating this.

Comment: @vivek_23 Hopefully, duplicate item ids should not be present the array in the first place.

Comment: First one is much faster https://3v4l.org/riIsS

Comment: @AbraCadaver If the search is for only 1 element, then the first approach is faster. If this goes inside a loop, then second one is better. https://3v4l.org/8lN2A5

Comment: @lephleg Great. If the search is for only 1 element, then the first approach is faster. If this goes inside a loop, then second one is better. https://3v4l.org/8lN2A5

Comment: Wow, great insights guys. This is actually inside a dual loop monstrosity, so I can definitely see the gains just by syntax refactoring it.

Comment: @vivek_23 The difference is that in the loop the array is getting smaller every iteration.  More code would be needed to see which is faster with different code.

Comment: @AbraCadaver In both the approaches, the array of `$allowedItems` gets shrinked. The first one does get the advantage of search over a smaller space, but is still quadratic in nature. The other one does in O(1) time in the best case.

Comment: @lephleg It's a complete alogrithm refactor I would say.

Comment: @vivek_23 No, in my example I redefine`$allowedItems` to 1-10000 each loop iteration.  In yours it does the same but the inner loop reduces the array each time.

Comment: @AbraCadaver So does `unset($allowedItems[$key]);` in the first approach. Also, in the second approach `$flipped` never shrinks.